# Sending email with Javamail from a script without a password

Tags: testing, gmail, jakarta-mail

I have a script that runs a Java program to run some tests every night. It needs to email out the results of the tests, using JavaMail and a Google apps account.

How do I authenticate with Gmail (through the JavaMail API), without storing the password on the machine that runs the nightly tests? Can I get some sort of an Gmail authentication key that is valid for, say, a month? I don't mind refreshing the key every month, but don't want to keep the password on the test machine.

Google email accounts cost money so I would prefer not to create a new account just to email test results out.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried that myself but you can try to send in the mail using the MX servers of googlemail. Currently these are

```
~ $ host -t MX googlemail.com
googlemail.com mail is handled by 40 alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
googlemail.com mail is handled by 10 alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
googlemail.com mail is handled by 20 alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
googlemail.com mail is handled by 5 gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
googlemail.com mail is handled by 30 alt3.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
```

These are the servers responsible for inbound mails from the outside world, it's plain SMTP without the need of authentication (but you can try to start TLS to make the transfer more secure). There might be checks though, that prevent you from delivering mails to these servers (dyn-IP-checks, SFP, etc.) which is why this might fail.

If you don't want to send to a Google mail address you can try the same thing but replace the MX server of Google with the one responsible for the mail address you want to send to. Just use above call with the different domain or use one of the search results for "mx lookup" if you don't have that as command on your system.